# Converting groups of key:value pairs to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple text file that has groups of key:value pairs with a blank row between each group of key:values. The number of key:value pairs can vary from group to group. Sample data and my code so far.

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3

key1: value4
key2: value5
key3: value6
```

The code is close to what I am looking for, but the part that is missing is when it gets to a blank line I need it to close out the JSON and start a new one for the next group.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

f = open("sample.txt", "r")
content = f.read()
splitcontent = content.splitlines()

d = []
for v in splitcontent:
    l = v.split('\n')
    print(l)
    if l == ['']:
        continue
    d.append(dict(s.split(': ',1) for s in l))
    with open("dump.json", 'w') as file:
        file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```

I tried to use the l == [''] to end the JSON and it does skip the blank, but just continues which is expected just not what I need.

Thanks for the help and if you recognize the code above an extra thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import json

with open("sample.txt") as fp:
    data = {}
    i = 0
    for line in fp:
        if not line.strip():
            # Empty line: store original data, reset data
            with open(f"dump{i}.json", "w") as out:
                json.dump(data, out)
            i += 1
            data = {}
            continue
        key, value = line.split(':')
        data[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    # Write the final JSON data, if there's still data in it
    if data:
        with open(f"dump{i}.json", "w") as out:
            json.dump(data, out)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was even better than what I had asked for. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect empty lines like this

```
data = dict()
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line:
            # empty, write out a file and start new section 
            data = dict()
        else:
            k, v = line.split(':', 1) 
            data[k] = v
# done reading file - if last line is not empty, then there's still data in the dictionary that needs written
```

Note that you're overriding the same output file for both "sections"

Answer (score 0):

In your code youre saving the dict to a json file after every line, instead of doing it after every section ends.

The lines are all saved to the same json because you keep adding them to the same list. Instead you can create a list of lists, where every nested list represnt 1 sections.

In this solution they are still saved to the same json but are in separate dicts, not the same one as before:

```
d = []
sections = []
for v in splitcontent:
    l = v.split('\n')
    print(l)
    if l == ['']:
        # section ended, add it to the sections list
        sections.append(d)
        # clear out the list
        d = []
        continue
    d.append(dict(s.split(': ',1) for s in l))
# the last section was not added to the sections list if last line is not a blank one
if d != []:
    sections.append(d)

with open("dump.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write((json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys= False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `re` module to split up the file content by 2 or more newlines, and then process each group of entries.

```py
import json
import re

data = []

with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
    groups = re.split(r'\n{2,}', file.read())
    for group in groups:
        entries = group.strip().split("\n")
        entries = [entry.split(": ", 1) for entry in entries]
        entries = {e[0]:e[1] for e in entries}
        data.append(entries)

with open("dump.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys= False))
```